# Atualizar model parcialmente com WebAPI2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-2

Estou começando a desenvolver uma API REST usando ASP.NET WebAPI2.

No meu `controller`, estou usando o método **`PATCH`** para aplicar mudanças parciais a um `model`.

Tenho um método que está desta forma

```
[HttpPatch]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult EditarNome(int id, string novoNome)
{
    var cliente = _db.Clientes.Find(id);

    if (cliente == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    cliente.Nome = novoNome;

    _db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Este método, recebe como parâmetro um novo nome e atualiza a propriedade `Nome` do model.

Na hora de fazer a requisição o endpoint fica
**`api/Clientes/1?novoNome=JoaquimAlbertoSilva`**

Seguindo essa lógica, eu precisaria criar mais três métodos, para poder dar a opção do cliente editar apenas estas 4 propriedades do model **Cliente**.

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Esta abordagem esta certa? Devo fazer apenas um método?
- Seria melhor eu definir uma rota para cada tipo de alteração? Algo como:
  **`api/Clientes/1/EditarNome/{novoNome}`**
  **`api/Clientes/1/EditarApelido/{novoApelido}`**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Com essa abordagem você está sub-utilizando o poder do PATCH. A principal vantagem desse verbo é que o cliente pode enviar somente os atributos a serem alterados, e isso pode ser feito **no mesmo *resource***. Criar uma nova rota para cada atributo significa mais código que o necessário.

O que você precisa usar é o tipo [`Delta<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.delta.aspx) (você precisa incluir um novo pacote do NuGet, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData). Se você tem uma operação que recebe um parâmetro desse tipo, ele vai conter somente os parâmetros passados pelo cliente, e você pode chamara o método `Patch`, que aplica tais alterações, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
[HttpPatch]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult EditarNome(int id, Delta<Cliente> alteracoes)
{
    var cliente = _db.Clientes.Find(id);

    if (cliente == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    alteracoes.Patch(cliente);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Com esse método, o cliente pode enviar requisições PATCH para qualquer parte do registro a ser alterado. Por exemplo:

```
PATCH /api/Clientes/1
Content-Type: application/json
Outros-Headers: ...

{ "Nome": "Nome alterado" }
```

ou também:

```
PATCH /api/Clientes/1
Content-Type: application/json
Outros-Headers: ...

{ "Apelido": "Novo apelido" }
```

E você não precisa ter mais de um método para realizar a mesma função (atualizar o objeto no servidor).

Comment: Muito show o `Delta<T>`. +1.

Comment: Incrível. Pretendo testar o `Delta<T>` ainda. O problema é que eu não posso dar abertura para o cliente editar todo o model. Usando o `Delta<T>` o cliente pode enviar o objeto inteiro e fazer ele ser completamente atualizado.

Comment: Depois de pensar um pouco sobre isso, acho que essa é realmente uma solução muito mais elegante. Obrigado pela contribuição!

Answer (score 4):

> Esta abordagem está certa?

Sim, segundo [respaldo do RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), que explica como e quando usar o `PATCH`.

> Devo fazer apenas um método?

Se a atualização parcial exigir apenas um método, sim. Se você precisar de outros tipos de atualização parcial, terá de fazer mais métodos ou usar o objeto `Delta<T>` ([conforme a resposta do @carlosfigueira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/112933/2999)).

> Seria melhor eu definir uma rota para cada tipo de alteração?

Sim, eu diria que é uma abordagem das mais elegantes. Deixar tudo num método só também é uma opção, mas pode subir enormemente a complexidade.

### Importante!

Não existe meio-patch. Se fizer um patch, certifique-se de usar todos os atributos passados para o método. Qualquer coisa diferente disso é melhor usar `PUT` (se for uma atualização do objeto inteiro) ou `POST`.

Comment: Você não precisa de multiplas rotas - o Web API tem uma funcionalidade de aplicar somente as mudanças enviadas pelo cliente. Duplicar o código (via multiplas rotas) não é a melhor forma de lidar com esse problema.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Depende muito do que ele quer fazer. O `PATCH` é justamente para pequenas alterações. Como eu disse, se houver muitas delas, o correto é partir para o `PUT` ou `POST`.

Comment: A semântica do PUT é trocar o objeto que está no servidor pelo que foi enviado pelo cliente - ou seja, mudar **todas** as propriedades. Mesmo que haja muitas propriedades a serem alteradas, se o cliente não vai enviar *o objeto completo*, então PUT não é adequado. O POST deveria ser usado para criar novos recursos (objetos / entradas no BD, etc.) mas ele é tão utilizado para outros fins que não dá pra definir uma regra clara para ele... Mas nesse caso (alteração parcial de um objeto), o PATCH é o mais indicado.